# Developing an Asteroids successor: which languages/tools/frameworks?

Tags: java, flash, flex

Currently I'm planning to run the [Asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_%28video_game%29) successor on the Java Virtual Machine, while writing the code in Scala (because that's the language I'm fluent in).

I have looked at different options, like using one of the various OpenGL bindings or using Java2D.

Having looked at some frameworks it seems that they either are targeted at 3D development or [jump-and-run style games](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/).

Are there any useful frameworks or should I try to combine libraries from different origins and roll my own "framework"?

Are other frameworks/tools like Flash/Flex vastly superior, so that learning a new language/platform would only be a minor drawback compared to huge benefits?

Answer (score 2):

Flash has better penetration (everyone has the Flash plugin...), provides better tools for gaming (several 2d and 3d gaming engines like [Flixel](http://flixel.org/), [PushButton](http://pushbuttonengine.com/), [Alternativa](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/), [Away3d](http://away3d.com/), [Fisix](http://www.fisixengine.com/)) as well as better tools for creating graphics (Flash IDE, Vector based graphics).  And to top it all off, you can port it to any mobile device using Air (iOS, Android, Playbook, Win7 in the works).

Flash gaming is a fairly big part of Flash in itself.  It's been around forever.  Very good community support as well.

Comment: Oh, and don't use Flex.  It's for RIA, not games.

Comment: "Flex" is a vague term that Adobe made purposely inexact. You could mean the Flex Builder, in which case yeah don't bother with that. You could also mean an application designed through MXML, in which case yeah that's mostly for rich internet applications. However I tend to use Flex to refer to the free compiler that doesn't require the Flash IDE, in which case that's a great way to develop web games.

Comment: @jhocking, Adobe has rectified that with Flash Builder which came out Mar. 2010.  Flex now only refers to the framework sdk.

Comment: thanks, that eliminates the first of the three possibilities I listed. That still leaves the other two, so it's still not exactly correct to say "don't use Flex for games."

Comment: what other two?  Flex is only the framework.  Nobody references 'Flex' for the 'free compiler'.

Comment: The free compiler is the Flex SDK. And yeah "Flex SDK" is a more specific term than just Flex, but that's why I said "Flex" is a confusing term. When discussing the framework specifically I say that because just saying Flex can confuse people.

Comment: I'd agree with you, but then we'd both be wrong.  There is a compiler in the Flex SDK *called* mxmlc; saying that a compiler IS Flex is not even close the the definition.

Comment: Well the point I'm getting at is that your comment "don't use flex" could be misleading to poor soc here. If you instead said "don't use the flex framework because that's for RIA, but do download the Flex SDK for developing your game" then I'll happily go through deleting all my comments regarding Flex.

Comment: I believe this answer is no longer as accurate as it may have been. Flash adoption seems to have gone way down last couple of years and has been or is about to be dropped from many browsers.